# Geodatabase to PostGIS character encoding

Tags: postgis, convert, esri-geodatabase, ogr

Similar to another question I posted previously, I'm trying to import datasets from Esri geodatabases into a PostGIS database directly, and inside the data, there are greek letters and symbols that are not converting correctly.  I tried using FWTools on Windows with a command like this:

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=server.domain.com user=gisuser dbname=gis"
dataset.mdb LayerName -a_srs EPSG:4326
```

The first time I tried, I got this error from ogr2ogr:

ERROR 1: INSERT command for new feature failed.
ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xb4
HINT: This error can also happen if the byte sequence does not match the
encoding expected by the server, which is controlled by "client_encoding".

I found out that setting a particular environment variable at the Windows command line can fix this issue:

```
SET PGCLIENTENCODING=LATIN1
```

That fixed importing problem -- all the records and geometry are in PostGIS, but as a result, the non-English characters are not encoded correctly.  When I use `UTF-8` or `UTF8` for client encoding (not sure which is correct), I get the same invalid byte sequence error as above.  Has anyone else had this problem or found a way around it?  Is this an issue with the .mdb file itself, or is there something on the server I can change to globally correct this?

Comment: I haven't had exactly that error, but encodings can really be a pain sometimes :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Greek isn't LATIN1, try

```
SET PGCLIENTENCODING=ISO_8859_7
```

Comment: Oh, and in the "teach a man to fish" category, I found that answer here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/multibyte.html

Answer (score 1):

some great looking documentation in this google search.
convert latin to unicode

http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=convert+latin+to+unicode&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&psj=1&fp=9085ebf0eb5276e9

Comment: which google search?